# How to drop the first n rows that has a NaN value in the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:
[image]
And I need to drop the first 4 rows because they have NaN as a value in the first column. Since I'll have to do this to slightly different dataframes I can't just drop them by index.
To achieve this I thought of iterating over the df by rows, checking if the value is NaN using numpy `isnan` function and then drop the row - sadly it doesn't seem to work.

```
first_col = df.columns[0]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if np.isnan(row[first_col]):
        df.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)
    else:
        break
```

`isnan` does not work though.
So I tried replacing NaN values with a blank string `df.fillna("", inplace=True)` and replaced the if condition:

```
first_col = df.columns[0]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[first_col] == '':
        df.drop(i, inplace=True, axis=0)
    else:
        break
```

This works, but it's pretty ugly alright. Is there a faster/neater way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
df['num.ord.tariffa'] = df['num.ord.tariffa'].fillna('Remove')
newdf = df[df['num.ord.tariffa'] != 'Remove']
```

EDIT:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
n = 4
for index,row in df.iterrows():
   if index < n:
        if row['c1'] == np.nan:
           pass
        else:
           new = pd.DataFrame([[row['c1'],row['c2']]],columns=['c1','c2'])
           final = final.append(new)
   else:
        new = pd.DataFrame([[row['c1'],row['c2']]],columns=['c1','c2'])
        final = final.append(new)
```

Comment: This would work if I had to remove _all_ of the rows with NaN value in that column. Instead I just have to remove the ones before the first valid value - there are more rows after the fifth.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your full dataset because of the way you posted it but you can do this:

Assume a `df` (which is similar to your first column):

```
  num.ord.tariffa
0             NaN
1             NaN
2             NaN
3             NaN
4               5
5               6
6               7
```

You use `.loc`, and `argmax()`:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1).argmax():]
```

and get back:

```
  num.ord.tariffa
4               5
5               6
6               7
```

Which removes `np.nan` until the first `non-nan`, which is your desired result.

Comment: My df is similar to the one you used, but I can't seem to replicate this approach on mine...

Answer (score 0):

You should drop rows with Nan values and add a subset of the columns you are interested:

```
df = df.dropna(subset='num.ord.tariffa')
```